# Databinding layout error Error while using @={} in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-databinding

I have done lots of research and found that @={} is used for two way binding. However if i used the sysbol i get an error that binding package is not available.

If I used the @{} the databinding is working properly.But this is only one way.

Below is the code that I use to bind the edit text view.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="ItemPricing"
            type="com.san.viewmodels.Item.ItemPricing" />
    </data>

 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/item_one"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@={String.valueOf(ItemPricing.unitPrice1)}" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is the adapter

```
public class ItemPricingRecylerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemPricingRecylerAdapter.DataViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ItemPricing> data = Collections.emptyList();
    Context context;

    public ItemPricingRecylerAdapter(List<ItemPricing> data, Context context) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public DataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemLayoutBinding binding = ItemLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater);
        DataViewHolder dataViewHolder = new DataViewHolder(binding);
        return dataViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(DataViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemPricing current = data.get(position);
        holder.cBinding.setItemPricing(current);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ItemLayoutBinding cBinding;

        public DataViewHolder(ItemLayoutBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.cBinding = binding;
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error for ItemLayoutBinding package is not available if I used the @={}

here is the POJO model

```
public class ItemPricing {
private int unitPrice1;

    public int getUnitPrice1() {
        return this.unitPrice1;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice1(int unitPrice1) {
        this.unitPrice1 = unitPrice1;
    }}
```

Keep getting this error 
[image]

What I am doing wrong? I am not able to resolve this issue from long time.

Please is anyone know how to resolve this issue

Comment: There will be a well mentioned error in your logcat, just go to the end of your logs, you will find a specific error with description.

Answer (score 0):

@={user.email}

android:text='@={ItemPricing.unitPrice1+""}'

can u tried on that way?

Comment: Same error...... "Error:(8, 34) error: package com.san.common.databinding does not exist" and "Error:(53, 9) error: cannot find symbol class ItemLayoutBinding"

Comment: I am facing the error while I use @=. why? I have the latest android studio and latest gradle